# How to track an anonymous user in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to allow users to add products to their basket without being connected in Meteor, currently I am using the IP address but it's a bad solution because it's shared between multiple users if behind a router (eg: everyone in a home / office have the same basket...).

Basically, if the user refreshes the page, he should not lose his basket content, so using Session is not acceptable.

Maybe using a Cookie ? what do you think ? any advice ?
I need something reliable and persistent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store it as a persistent session variable.
Check https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session